# GeoServer WMS Layers not overlaying on OSM base-Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, leaflet, openstreetmap, wms

I would like to understand why I cannot view or see the WMS layers loaded. Based on the investigation I did so far, I am assuming this has to do with base layers projections. My overlays are WGS84, EPSG 4326. Any guidance on how to resolve this?

This is what I currently see:
[image]

```
    <script>
      //Base Layers
      var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18
      });

      var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
 });

      var uis_erven = new L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Erongo/wms", "Erongo:uis_erven", {
        layers: 'uis_erven',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: '',
      });

      var uis_erven_layout = new L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Erongo/wms", "Erongo:uis_erven_layout", {
        layers: 'uis_erven_layout',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: '',
      });

      //create the map
      var map = L.map('map', {
        zoomControl:true,
        zoom: 14,
        maxZoom:18,
        minZoom:5,
        center: new L.LatLng(-21.2531795501709, 14.8524971008301),
        fullscreenControl: true,
        layers: [OSM, uis_erven, uis_erven_layout]
      });
      //layer control
      var baseMaps = {
        "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
        "ESRI  World Imnagery": Esri_WorldImagery
      };
      var overlayMaps = {
        "Zonning": uis_erven,
        "Erven Layout": uis_erven_layout,
      };
      L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: look in the browser JS debugger and see what is returned in the "images" from GeoServer - it is likely to be the error message

Comment: if you look for the WMS images and check the preview I think you will see error messages in the images

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader">
      No LAYERS has been requested
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>

Comment: @TomazicM I did that, kindly refer to my previous answer.

Comment: You posted it while I was typing and so I didn't see it. Please take a look at the WMS request that goes to server and add it to your question. And one thing more: you have second parameter `"Erongo:uis_erven_layout"` in your WMS call. There is no such parameter in Leaflet docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-wms

Comment: OK now we need to examine the URL that is generating that error, does it have a LAYERS= parameter (because GeoServer doesn't think so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error returned by GeoServer says there are no layers in the request you are making, so no map gets drawn. Looking at the [Leaflet manual](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html) suggests that you need to provide an options object with the layers parameter in it. So something like this should work:

```
var uis_erven = new L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Erongo/wms", {
        layers: "Erongo:uis_erven",
      });
```

None of your other options were necessary as I think they are all the default anyway, you can add them back if you need.

Comment: Success, thank you so much Ian Turton.

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus If answer helped you solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted, not only upvote it.

Comment: @TomazicM noted.